# How to Hide specific value in a dropdown (a collection list) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to hide **an element from a collection** not a manual set.

```
<tr>
 <td> <%= f.label :department, 'Select a Department, 
 you want to report to  : ' %>  <br> </td>
 <td><%= collection_select(:feedback, :department_id, Department.order('name ASC'),    
 :id, :name) %></td>
```

Now the Deparment list is having admin, cat1,cat2,cat3 etc. I want to hide the admin from the 
dropdown. How to Do that  ?

Comment: Remove it from the collection. I'm not convinced doing this in the view layer is a great idea.

Comment: first fetch the Department is some other variable and condition so that it will not show admin then put put it in the result in the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use SQL statements from within your view. That's what the controller is for.

```
def edit_action
   @departments = Department.where('name != admin').order('name ASC').all
end
```

Now you can use the @departments variable in your edit_action.html.erb (or whatever its name really is in your case).

```
<td><%= collection_select(:feedback, :department_id, @departments, :id, :name) %></td>
```

However, you should not create too many of these global variables starting with `@`. The rule is 3 or 4 max I think. Alternatively you can use local variables and pass them to your view like this.

```
def edit_action
   departments = Department.where('name != admin').order('name ASC').all
   render :action => 'edit_action', :locals => { :depts => departments }
end

<td><%= collection_select(:feedback, :department_id, depts, :id, :name) %></td>
```

As for your admin option you want to hide. You need to remove it from the collection before passing it to your view. Removing it in your view with some kind of condition or name matching is error prone and not recommended.

Comment: "You should not use SQL statements from within your view. That's what the controller is for."  Actually I would say the SQL is the job of the model.

Comment: Personally I only create scopes or filtering functions if they are used in more than one occasion. The model should only contain common logic not specific to single views.

Comment: <td><%= collection_select(:feedback, :department_id, [@department], :id, :name) %></td>
[ ] section should be @departments. 

I prefer your second Approach, as in my case I need to hide different user types for different logins. I would love to go with 2nd Approach.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup with the typo. Both approaches are basically the same but I found that in too many cases, global variables get used a bit too much in controllers, which is kind of a bad practice. Still, globals are easier to spot inbetween all the erb code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from the collection

```
 <%= collection_select(:feedback, :department_id, Department.where("name <> 'admin'").order('name ASC'),    
     :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: This level of business logic should not really be in the view.  Have the model define this, have the controller call the method and set an instance variable for use in the view.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean: I completely agree with you I just mentioned the way to achieve it.